# Drag and drop cross domains, iframes, browsers windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-domain, drag

Thanks stackoverflow i solved a lot of my javascript problems, but now i stopped at the point without hope. It is hard to describe, there is clear video shows my problem with drag drop cross-domains iframe.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v65mO27h75E

- First part in Iceweasel (and FF, Opera) = iframe d&d work OK.
- Second part in Chromium (and Chrome) = iframe d&d NOT work.

and there are links to example iframes set and iframes sources:

- parent page: http:// msdrop.com/msdrop-jquery-test-iframe-frameset.htm
- iframe A: http:// msdrop.com
- iframe B: http:// nextgd.com/msdrop-jquery-test-iframe.htm

Is it Chrome bug, or security that comes under "Same origin policy"? This is strange because d&d works excellent between two windows, and want not work at all from parent window to iframe.

Thanks for suggestions.
Piotr

EDIT: It's possible Chrome/Chromium security mitigation is overly broad. Issue 251718: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=251718

Comment: Open your chrome dev tools and select the console tab. Then attempt your drag and drop. What error appears? I know from experience that same-origin policy violations get logged to the console.

Comment: You can test too, there is online sample link: http://msdrop.com/msdrop-jquery-test-iframe-frameset.htm A JavaScript Console **do not show any errors or unsafe JavaScript attempt to access**. There is nothing special or unsafe at iframe B: http://nextgd.com/msdrop-jquery-test-iframe.htm

Comment: Here is second video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CnSXCRJJLEU that show Chrome iframe drag and drop problem. Sample page:  http://www.byckobieta.pl/ulubione.php Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

Now, at: http://msdrop.com/msdrop-jquery-test-iframe-frameset.htm there are 4 iframes

- IFRAME A: the same domain as parent
- IFRAME B: other domain
- IFRAME C: the same domain + sandbox="allow-scripts"
- IFRAME D: other domain + sandbox="allow-scripts"

In FF, all frames works that i expects.

In Chrome, and Chromium only on iframe A works all dragover, dragenter, dragleave, and drop events.

Comment: I know this is old, but for what it's worth none of the three frames on the right load anything anymore, when inspected they're simply flashing as if reloading infinitely.

Answer (score 1):

i think i found answer, drag and drop events works on iframe when open Chromium or Chrome without restrictions.

chromium-browser --disable-web-security

google-chrome --disable-web-security

But if it is about Google Chrome "web security", why JavaScript Console do not show any info or warrning, and why drag and drop works excellent between two windows, drag and drop works even from firefox to chrome.

edit: Google Chrome: "You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --disable-web-security. Stability and security will suffer." so flag works but is unsupported?

I do not understand.

Answer (score 1):

Adding sandbox="allow-scripts" to the iframe element solves this issue for me.

eg:

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" src=".." />
```

Comment: I tested it, and in theory it should works, but it works in reverse, when sandbox="allow-scripts" is set, scripts wont not work even in the same domain. Tested with Linux Chrome "27.0.1453.93", Windows Chrome  "27.0.1453.116 m", Linux Chromium "6.0.472.63 (59945)". I put IFRAME C with sandbox="allow-scripts", Are there works dragover dragenter dragleave or dragdrop events on your Chrome browser?