# Drag&drop text to gas web application's iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-apps-script, web-applications, bookmarklet

I'm coding an google app script which grab selected text as parameter and open new window via a bookmarklet. I'm trying `select&drag&drop` some text or link to web application `input/textarea` which works on opened window example: `https://script.google.com/macros/s/.../exec?article=`.

The problem is when I allow iframe with `.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)` and add `https://script.google.com/macros/s/.../exec?article=` page in an iframe instead of opening in a new page; `drag&dropping` text became disabled. Is there anyway to enable drag&drop text to iframe's input box?

`drag&drop` is available in normal `https://script.google.com/macros/s/.../exec?article=` page but not in an iframe.

Also thanks to comments I tried it on Firefox and it works, but still not on Chrome

GAS

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('')
    .append('<input type="text" id="kind" placeholder="Kind" size="4" value="' + (e.parameter.article?e.parameter.article:"") + '">')
  .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
  Logger.log(e);
}
```

Bookmarklet opening new page

```
javascript:if(window.getSelection)s=window.getSelection(); else if(document.getSelection)s=document.getSelection(); else if(document.selection)s=document.selection.createRange().text;     open('https://script.google.com/macros/s/...GAS.ID.../exec?article=article'+(location.host=='scholar.google.com'?'':'&pdf='+encodeURIComponent(location.href))+'&bib='+encodeURIComponent(s.toString())+'bib');0
```

Bookmarklet adding iframe

```
javascript:if(window.getSelection)s=window.getSelection();else if(document.getSelection)s=document.getSelection();else if(document.selection)s=document.selection.createRange().text;    iframe=document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('iframe'));iframe.style='position:fixed;bottom:0;z-index:99999;width:280px;'; iframe.src='https://script.google.com/macros/s/...GAS.ID.../exec?article=article'+(location.host=='scholar.google.com'?'':'&pdf='+encodeURIComponent(location.href))+'&bib='+encodeURIComponent(s.toString());0
```

*replace "/...GAS.ID.../" with web application id in bookmarklet

Comment: [Related?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968818)

Comment: Yes, I think it is. But there isn't any solution either

Comment: [Edit] your post to include the browser that you're testing with. Does Firefox work? If it's a browser specific issue, then you need to open a bug report at that browser's bug tracker

Comment: [Comment#12](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=251718#c12) has a workaround. Also see related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56400626).

Comment: @TheMaster thanks for the links, I was hoping an attribute like sandbox ="allow-drag-drop" but probably there no way around